# Error: A value of type 'Contacto' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, content-provider

Estoy tratando de usar `Flutter` con `Provider` pero no funciona

se `ChangeNotifierProvider` el problema es el mismo, de que el `provider` debe se un `widget`, y que no acepta `builder`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => Contacto()),//Línea de Error
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Provider Example',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: 'home',
        routes: {
          'home': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Store**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Contacto with ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void add() {
    this.counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void sus() {
    this.counter--;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void adds(counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial ese parametro no existe, debes usar `create` en lugar de builder.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Contacto()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Provider Example',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: 'home',
        routes: {
          'home': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mas info https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html